# Entity Framework Core - Cannot insert explicit value when saving to another table

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, sqlexception

I'm trying to create an 'Order' object that has a Collection of 'OrderItem's that holds a 'Hamper' object. Basically, whenever I try to save the 'Order' object to my database, I keep getting this error that I can't insert explict values into the table for my hampers, except I'm not altering the Hamper data, I'm simply using those objects within another object.
My hamper model has :

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Before the primary key object. I have no idea what to do to be perfectly honest and nothing I've found online has seemed to help. Whether I'm explicity adding the 'OrderItem' object one by one or the whole collection within the 'Order' object, I still can't get away from this error. I have linked the HamperID within the 'OrderItem' as a foriegn key, and I haven't had this issue when saving objects within other objects, it's just this example.
Anyway, here's the error. I wouldn't expect including the models would be much help, but the specific error is a follows:

```
Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 
'TblHamper' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

And here is the 'OrderItem' model that is causing the error whenever I try to save:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Hamper Hamper { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HamperID")]
    public int HamperID { get; set; }
```

Comment: It _sounds_ like the `Hamper` item isn't populated in your model structure before you try the insert. That would probably mean EF tries to generate a new insert for it when you add your `OrderItem`. I'd double check your model structure is fully populated with the references linked before you do the insert. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300982/ef-core-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column/45303486#45303486  - hope that is of some help

Comment: The hamper is already saved in the database, i'm just creating a link between them. It's the same thing i've done with other objects so that's why i'm really confused as to why it's not working here.

Comment: Sorry I mean if your object has a link to an existing `Hamper` then the data for that should be populated when you save the `OrderItem` otherwise EF will think it has to create a new entry for `Hamper`. It sounds like that is covered though and this is something else.

Comment: TblHamper has no Primary Key or Identity is off.  So it can't create the primary key when you insert.  You need to check if it got scaffold-ed correctly when you initially created and then updated that table with EF.  It appears it doesn't have key generator in place.  Check it via right click design view in VS on that table. IF `IDENTITY` is missing you will need either recreate table or try to get it re-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For `EF Core` to decide whether to update or create, it is controlled by `Tracking`. For your scenario, it seems you initialize a new `Hamper` when create a new `Order` with a new `OrderItem`.

Try options below:

- Reset `Hamper` with `Hamper` in database.

  ```
          Hamper hamper = new Hamper { Id = 1, Name = "H1" };
          Hamper dbHamper = _context.Hamper.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Id == hamper.Id);
          OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem { Title = "T1", HamperId = dbHamper.Id, Hamper = dbHamper };
          Order order = new Order { OrderNo = "O1", OrderItem = orderItem };
          await _context.Order.AddAsync(order);
          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  ```
- `Attach` to start `Tracking`

  ```
              Hamper hamper = new Hamper { Id = 1, Name = "H1" };
          _context.Attach(hamper);
          OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem { Title = "T1", HamperId = hamper.Id, Hamper = hamper };
          Order order = new Order { OrderNo = "O1", OrderItem = orderItem };
          await _context.Order.AddAsync(order);
          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  ```
- Or, you could pass the `HamperId`  without `Hamper`

  ```
              Hamper hamper = new Hamper { Id = 1, Name = "H1" };
          OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem { Title = "T1", HamperId = hamper.Id };
          Order order = new Order { OrderNo = "O1", OrderItem = orderItem };
          await _context.Order.AddAsync(order);
          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
IDbContextTransaction trn = testDBContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
Item itm = new Item();
itm.ItemId = 23;
itm.ItemName = "item23";
Type typt = typeof(Item);
DbSet<Item> Item1 = testDBContext.Set<Item>();
testDBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Item] ON");
//Item1.FromSql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Item] ON").SingleOrDefaultAsync();

testDBContext.Item.Add(itm);
testDBContext.SaveChanges(); 

//Item1.FromSql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Item] OFF").SingleOrDefaultAsync();
testDBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Item] OFF");
trn.Commit();
trn.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please submit an explanation to your answer so other users with a similar problem can understand what is happening.