# How to save an entity with a child entity which already exists in EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I ran into a very weird problem I've never seen before. I'm using .net CORE 3.0 + EF.
I have two database models, which are

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dog Dog { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Dog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, let's say I already have a Dog record in my database with id=1 and Name = "Bimbo". Now, I want to add a person with **an existing dog**:

```
var p = new Person
{
    Name = "Peter",
    Dog = new Dog
    {
        Id = 1
    };
};

_dbContext.Persons.Add(p);
```

Then I get

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Dogs' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

I understand that EF tries to insert a dog as a new record, while I need it to bind my new Person record with an existing Dog record.

I found this solution which suggests setting a foreign key explicitly. Is there another way to do it? Or is it the right way to handle such situation?
*[EF Core insert explicit value for identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300982/ef-core-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column/45303486#45303486)*

Comment: Load the existing dog instance from the context and assign that instance to the person Dog property, add that person to the context and save.

Comment: Yeah, I understand how to handle it. But this looks like a workaround for me. Wouldn't it be more logical if EF tried to find an existing dog with provided id?

Comment: EF does that only when you have a foreign key on person and when you set it explicitly. Having explicitly defined foreign keys is a good practice for EF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have three options to do that

1. Use the Foreign-Key property

   ```
   using ( var db = new MyDbContext(options) )
   {
       var person = new Person
       {
           Name = "Paul",
           DogId = 1
       };

       db.Persons.Add(person);
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   ```
2. Load the dog instance from the context and use that instance

   ```
   using ( var db = new MyDbContext(options) )
   {
       var dog = db.Dogs.Find(1);

       var person = new Person
       {
           Name = "Paul",
           Dog = dog
       };

       db.Persons.Add(person);
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   ```
3. Create a dog instance with explicit ID and attach that to the context

   ```
   using ( var db = new MyDbContext(options) )
   {
       var dog = new Dog
       {
           Id = 1
       };

       db.Attach(dog);

       var person = new Person
       {
           Name = "Paul",
           Dog = dog
       };

       db.Persons.Add(person);
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   ```

See working example on [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LE3XHH)

Comment: In case of EfCore - [ForeignKey("{your_key_id_ref}")] works fine, but by some reason if you see this field in DB, but not in model (your parent Object was created instead) - you need to re-create constraint (and add the same key field to your model +attribute to parent obj) by adding new db migration or re-create db/table from zero if it acceptable for you. Can't believe, that EF still has no mechanism to set parent object not from DB (with keyId) excepting making another one query to db to get this record.

Comment: Finally, a solution that worked for me! Using ForeignKey works like magic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can explicitly add the Foreign key to person

```
   public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DogId {get;set;}
        public Dog Dog { get; set; }
    }
```

then you can the add the dog as reference without load it to context

```
var p = new Person
{
    Name = "Peter",
    DogId = 1
};

_dbContext.Persons.Add(p)
```

;

Answer (score 1):

When you add the Person object to the context, EF sets its state to Added, as well as any object it references that has their primary key set (as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-3.0)). This is why EF tries to insert a new Dog object into the database with a new id, while the exception states that the ids for the Dogs table are generated by the database.

To work around this you can manually set the state of the new Dog object to Unchanged which will prevent EF from inserting a new record to the database.:

```
_dbContext.Entry(person.Dog).State = EntityState.Unchanged
```

Better solutions will be to add a DogId property to the Person object and set it instead of creating a new Dog instance or to load the Dog object from the database and set it to the Dog property of the Person object (as suggested in the comments).