# Creating an EF Core entity with an existing foreign property with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm using MVVM with EF Core. I have an entity that has a foreign property which is seeded to the database beforehand, as follows:

```cs
public class STOCK : EntityBase
{
    public string TEXT {get;set;}
    public decimal AMOUNT {get;set;}

    private TAX SALESTAX {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("SALESTAX")]
    public int SALESTAX_ID {get;set;}

    private TAX SPECIALTAX {get;set}
    [ForeignKey("SPECIALTAX")]
    public int SPECIALTAX_ID {get;set;}
}

public class TAX
{
    public int TAXCODE {get;set;}
    public string NAME {get;set;}
    
    public ICollection<STOCK> STOCK_TAX {get;set;}
    public ICollection<STOCK> STOCK_SPECIAL {get;set}
}

public class EntityBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    //The interface is fully implemented here. Removed for brevity.
}
```

On my ViewModel I inject both a `StockDataService` as well as a `TaxDataService`, as follows:

```cs
public class StockDataService : IStockDataService
{
    private readonly MyDbContextFactory _factory;
    
    public StockDataService(MyDbContextFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task<STOCK> Create(STOCK entity)
    {
        using MyDbContext context = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        STOCK createdResult = await context.STOCKs.AddAsync(entity);
        return createdResult;
    } //Other CRUD methods are implemented as well, but removed for brevity.
}

public class TaxDataService : ITaxDataService
{
    private readonly MyDbContextFactory _factory;
    
    public TaxDataService(MyDbContextFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task<TAX> GetAll()
    {
        using MyDbContext context = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        return await context.TAXs.ToListAsync();
    }//Ditto
}
```

My view has a combobox as follows:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TAXES}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SALESTAX, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"  
          SelectedItem="{Binding SALESTAX}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                <Border Padding="0,0,2,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                    <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding TAXCODE}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
                <Border Padding="2,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                    <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding TEXT}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

My viewModel is as follows:

```cs
public class StockCrudViewModel
{
    private readonly IStockDataService _stockDataService;
    private readonly ITaxDataService _taxDataService;
    public STOCK CurrentStock {get;set;}

    public ICollection<TAX> TAXES {get;set;}

    public StockCrudViewModel(IStockDataService stockDataService, ITaxDataService taxDataService)
    {
        _stockDataService = stockDataService;
        _taxDataService = taxDataService;

        FillTaxesList();
    }

    private async void FillTaxesList()
    {
        TAXES = new List<TAX>(await _taxDataService.GetAll());
    }
```

The "save" command is as follows:

```cs
await _stockDataService.Create(_stockCrudViewModel.STOCK);
//Both the data service as well as the scoped view model are passed via dependency injection to the command.
```

EDIT: My `DbContextHostBuilder` is as follows:

```cs
host.ConfigureServices((context, myServices) =>
     {
         string connString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("default");
         Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> configureDbContext = c => { c.UseMySql(connString); c.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); };
         myServices.AddSingleton<MyDbContextFactory>(new MyDbContextFactory(configureDbContext));
         myServices.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(configureDbContext);
     });
```

Now, I understand why doing this will raise an "attempted to create a duplicate entry" exception, as setting the `SALESTAX` property via binding will be using a `TAX` coming from a different instance of `MyDbContext`, so EF Core can't track it accordingly. However, since I'm using `AddDbContext`, and passing the factory, rather than the context itself, instantiating a new context every time one of the data service methods is called, I'm not sure how to let EF Core know there is already an existing `TAX` entry that should be used.

According to [How to save an entity with a child entity which already exists in EF core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901164/how-to-save-an-entity-with-a-child-entity-which-already-exists-in-ef-core), they suggest fetching the existing entry using the same context used to create the new entry. But if my entity has five or more foreign properties, wouldn't that affect the performance? Or have I messed up somewhere back when planning the MVVM architecture?

Comment: If the object has its ID set, you can call `DbContext.Update` on it before you save the changes. By the way, you're all over the place when it comes to naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry about the names, I just translated the original names to english for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or have I messed up somewhere back when planning the MVVM architecture?

Yes.  The correct scope and lifetime for your DbContext in MVVM is on the ViewModel.

This gives you a single ChangeTracker and Unit Of Work for the ViewModel, and enables data binding to the loaded entities using the [Local Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.local?view=efcore-5.0), which is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Who is to say those services are not singleton? They could very well be, even if not in this case. This is WPF, so the concept of request doesn't apply here.

Comment: Oops, missed it was WPF.  Updating.

Comment: Understood. However, all my data services are also injected, and their dbcontexts are set via injection. How can I set injected dataservices' dbcontexts within a scope? All my dataservices are registered like `myServices.AddSingleton<IStockDataService, StockDataService>();` on my `HostBuilder` (other than changing `Singleton` to `Scoped`)

Comment: You add the DbContext as a Scoped service, and hang the scope off of you ViewModel.  Then make your Singleton services Scoped or Transient.

Comment: Hmm... Now I'm getting a `System.InvalidOperationException` for two concurrent operations on a single DbContext... Which is why I though I had to use injected factories

Comment: DbContext instances are not thread-safe, which means they can't be used concurrently in a single scope.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't scoping my viewmodels correctly. Do you know where I can find some more info on how to use scoped services other than the MS documentation?

Comment: It did work, by the way. All I had to do was inject the service provider and ask for a new scope on the view model's ctor. Thanks very much!!!!